# How to increase the number of available chapters for an HL2: EP2 mod?

Tags: c++, maps, modding

I created a mod for Half-Life 2: Episode 2 that has 39 chapters (or maps, here it is the same). The problem is that the game seems to see only 32: when clicking "new game", and clicking next, I count only 32/39.

Then, I went to the mod/cfg folder, I removed some of the chapter.cfg and whatever the number of the chapter, it is the sum of chapters that can't be above 32.

I tried to search on the Internet, but it seems that the only guy having a "quite" similar issue is here: [Fix broken Portal 2 chapter handling in my mod](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/34847/fix-broken-portal-2-chapter-handling-in-my-mod) (and he never had an answer).

As he did, I tried to modify the sv_unlockedchapters variable in config_default.cfg by putting it to 99, so every chapter is unlocked.

So here is my question: where is the parameter or the variable that fix the maximum number of maps?

I guess it would be in a .cpp file, and I tried to find it, but I do not have any knowledge in C++ programming, nor on how Valve organize their files.